# Animated Human model (actor) ROS Kinetic, gazebo7

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

I am new with Gazebo. I need to simulated an animated human model (something like the [actor](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=actor&cat=build_robo) model for Gazebo8.0) but unfortunately Ros Kinetic works with Gazebo7 which does not support actors.

I want to know do you have any idea how I can import an animated human model (where I can follow his/her legs with LaserScan)?

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18177/animated-human-model-(actor)-ros-kinetic,-gazebo7/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4256/mobile_robot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How about using ROS Kinetic with Gazebo 8? See this tutorial:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4256/mobile_robot/) on 2018-01-05**:
Thanks a lot for your suggestion. we have already tried that. Our simulation is too much depended on Gazebo 7 and changing to 8 leads to an enormous adaptation work... this is why I search a solution that I can insert an actor in Gazebo7

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-01-05**:
Unfortunately, the last I checked, actors weren't working properly on Gazebo 7, so I think that would require patch to Gazebo.